# Export an access query in csv without currency symbol using VBA

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm using this code to export a query in a CSV file:

```
Dim getFolder As Object
Dim sLoc As String
Dim sName As String

sName = Me.Name
Set getFolder = Application.FileDialog(4)
With getFolder
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = True Then
        sLoc = getFolder.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End If
End With
     DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "csv", sName & "_Csv", sLoc & sName & ".csv", True
```

However, there is a field that is in currency format, and in the csv file it exports this field with the currency symbol ahead of the numeric value, for example:

```
test|||||0|0|0|0|0||€ 123,00
```

Unfortunately, I need to import this in a website that use PrestaShop and the currency symbol cause trouble. How can I prevent the symbol to appear in the CSV file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the query you export to csv to have a field with this expression:

```
Format([YourCurrencyField], "Standard")
```

Not sure, though, if that is "cleaner".

Answer (score 3):

Open the query in design view and change the format for that field, to Standard.

Comment: Thanks, but it is a sort of workaround. I wanted a "cleaner" way to do that ;)

Comment: @AlexK. I know right.  If there is something that isn't clean about this Ponzaro please expand.

Comment: Using the format function is not cleaner as it converts the values to text.

Comment: Ah - great humour! What does a csv file contain in your country?